# How can we replace T4 with Roslyn when we need to have template output artefacts generated

Tags: code-generation, roslyn, t4

We have a number of templates written using T4 and the tangible multiple file generation library.

One example of this is as follows: -

A number of Entity objects in a C# library inheriting from a "BaseEntity" and attributed with a "RequiresAudit" attribute.

These entities are located and analysed in a T4 template by the afore mentioned inheritance of "BaseEntity" and attribution of "RequiresAudit".

Once analysed the T4 produces 3 trigger files of SQL that are applied in a legacy tool by the DB team and a documentation file in a JSON format.

So we require that the T4 produce a number of artefacts from the template run - 3 "Entity.SQL" files and a "docs.json" file.

All of our new code on the .NET side will be moved to .NET 5, this is the only big-bang our managers are prepared to undertake at this stage.

Question...

How can we make use of a Roslyn Analyser or Generator to do exactly the same job ?
We must have the generated files in our project available. How do we achieve this ?
Can anyone give a good example ?
Can Roslyn include the files in the project as an embedded resource, if so how ?

We really want to learn Roslyn, but we're also scared we could be wasting effort.

T4 support seems to be lacking on the VS2019 preview (when using .net 5 anyway) and I'm also concerned the movement in tech appears to be gravitating towards the Roslyn world anyway and that T4 may be nearing an end of life.

All of the documents I've read about Roslyn Code Generators don't appear to leave behind any files and simply compile a set of features into the assembly without any trace of the code source files. I just can't seem to find an obvious way to go from T4 to Roslyn in the same way that t4 works.

I don't need the "why are you doing it like this ?" comments. We can't change much. Just a nice friendly way (example) to solve the problem without re-writing the various touch-points we have in our legacy system.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your scenario carefully, your generated files are SQL or JSON; right now any generated file generated by a source generator is presumed to be a C# file, and is implicitly included in the compilation. We don't have support (yet) for just writing out other files in your case. As of 16.8 Preview 4 there is a property you can now set to have the C# files also written to a directory as a part of the actual compilation step, but again it's still C# files only.

This is absolutely something we're thinking about (the source generator design team literally had a meeting on it last week starting to think about this case) but we haven't outright committed to the scenario yet nor do we have timeline where we might ship something.

Comment: Hi Jason. Thanks for the info. I'm sure there are a large number of teams out there who face this scenario and went down the "generated artefact" route by the very nature of what T4 did. In our team its not just the SQL and JSON, other T4's are there doing lots of other generation. Sure some of what we do could be compiled into a class but that's not true of all of it. Really glad you have it on the radar though, at least that gives us some hope that Roslyn will be the way forward, really hope that file artefacts will appear soon. We'll keep an eye out. We're doing our research on VS Preview.

Comment: "As of 16.8 Preview 4 there is a property you can now set to have the C# files also written to a directory as a part of the actual compilation step, but again it's still C# files only." What is the property ? Do you have a URL to an example project?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/47047 was the PR that implemented it. I'm not sure we have an example but you can set EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles to true to enable it, and set CompilerGeneratedFilesOutputPath  if you want to change the path it gets set to.